# NLog Define multiple identical final rules with different log levels for multiple targets

Tags: nlog, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to log messages with `NLog` to multiple targets, with multiple `final` rules.

### Situation

NLog Version: `4.7.5` 
Plattform: `.NET CORE 3.1` 
Config: `XML File` and `configured programmatically`

I have 2 targets `File` and `Console`

```c#
LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(fileTarget);
LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(consoleTarget);
```

And multiple rules like

```c#
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A*",                           Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = true};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot*",                       Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = true};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of*",                    Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Info,  Final = true};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of.Hierarchical*",       Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Info,  Final = true};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of.Hierarchical.Rules*", Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Debug, Final = true};

new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A*",                           Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = true};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot*",                       Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = true};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of*",                    Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = true};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of.Hierarchical*",       Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = true};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of.Hierarchical.Rules*", Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Trace, Final = true};
```

*I know that `Target` and `MinLevel` are no valid properties, but it's easier to show*

The `Rules` must be `final`, otherwise all my log messages are duplicated.

EDIT: The users can change the `LogLevel` for each `rule` and for each `target` on runtime.

### Problem

When I crate a new `rule`, I have to set the `targets` for this `rule`. When I add multiple `targets` to one rule, I get the message in each target **but I can only define the `LogLevel` for both `targets`.** And when I add the `rule` twice, with one `target` for each `rule`, then I get the messages only in the console and not in the file, because the `final` stops the other `rules`.

I've already checked the NLog Page, NLog GitHub and StackOverflow pages. All their problems are how to log to multiple targets, or log to multiple targets with different rules but only with one rule per target.

### Expected

Define multiple `final` `rules` with different `LogLevel` for each Target

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping by target, then I suggest grouping them by logger-name-pattern, and have the most specific logger-name-pattern at the top:

```
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of.Hierarchical.Rules*", Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Debug, Final = false};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of.Hierarchical.Rules*", Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Trace, Final = true};

new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of.Hierarchical*",       Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = false};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of.Hierarchical*",       Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Info,  Final = true};

new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of*",                    Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Info,  Final = false};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot.Of*",                    Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = true};

new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot*",                       Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = false};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A.Lot*",                       Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = true};

new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A*",                           Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = false};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "A*",                           Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = true};

new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "*",                            Target = fileTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = false};
new LoggingRule() {LoggerNamePattern = "*",                            Target = consoleTarget, MinLevel = Warn,  Final = false};
```

You can also create "blackhole" logging-rules without any targets. By setting minLevel = Trace and Final = true. Then any output matching the LoggerNamePattern will not flow down to any rules that might follow.

But maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#logger-name-filter

Comment: I think, this won't work, because the users can change the `LogLevel` on runtime for each rule and each target. But i will try it.

Comment: @TheBigNeo If the user is changing the NLog-config directly, then I guess the user knows how to use NLog. If user don't know it works, then you probably need to build a config-editor-tool to protect the user from doing harm.

Comment: The users who need additional targets can do this manually in the config file. They have to deal with NLog. The users who only change the `LogLevel` can do this via the GUI, because we have the config file and also the programmed config

Comment: So it isn't possible?

Comment: @TheBigNeo I just showed you how to use final-rules. Believe that was the question. Sounds like you are building an exciting and solution for your users, and NLog has strong support for filtering and configuration.